# Google Apps Script searchFiles using readers in query

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get files under a folder that a user has view permissions. I'm using getFolderById and searchFiles.

Referring to this page https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms, I'm trying to use the 'readers' query term, like:

```
let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("<id of folder>");

let files = folder.searchFiles(Utilities.formatString("'%s' in readers", email));

while(files.hasNext()){

}
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the query correctly, this worked until on one folder, I get an error in the 'while' line:
Exception: Invalid argument

It looks like it generates an error if the user has no permission on any file under the folder, because if I try it with a user that actually has permission, it works.

But should the function just return a false hasNext() value instead?

Or am I using this incorrectly?

Thank in advance!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. When I try to replicate this, `hasNext` returns `false` if there's no file with view permission, as you suggested. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thank you @Iamblichus. The problem does not occur for all folders, hasNext() generates the error instead of returning true or false. The code I provided above is the actual example. I get a folder, and try to iterate through the files in it.

Comment: I have new information on this. It looks like certain characters in the query triggers it. Using this code as basis:

let files = folder.searchFiles("'myname@gmail.com' in readers");

This works. Changing the email so that it contains a hypen (my-name@gmail.com), a period (my.name@gmail.com), or 'email' (myemail@gmail.com) triggers the error.
Adding a '\' before the period works, but not with the hyphen. Maybe it's a bug with the searchFiles() function, or I'm missing how to format the query. Thanks!

Comment: When I try to test this, it seems like this fails if the email address doesn't exist. Can you please check whether that's the case for you?

Comment: Yes I have tried it, see my previous comment. The email is not valid (it does not exist in Gmail) and is not assigned to any folder nor file. The hasNext function triggers no error and correctly returns false. But it triggers the error if I use any of the characters or 'email' word in the email. I have sent an email to Google reporting this.

Comment: Have you reported this via Google Issue Tracker? If that's the case, would you consider posting an answer here referencing the corresponding issue? If that's not the case, I'd consider doing this.

Comment: I had sent an email, but now have reported in the Issue Tracker as you mentioned. Thank you for your time @Iamblichus.

Comment: Can you reference the issue here to give it more visibility?

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this right, but here is the link [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261903085).

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported by the OP in Issue Tracker. Referencing it here to give it more visibility:

- [searchFiles function triggers an error with certain characters and word](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261903085)

Comment: What really burns me up is that I can't use the `contains` operator. I want to find all files that are shared outside the organization (e.g. contains "@gmail.com" but *it stupidly refuses to accept the contains operations*!?!)